# How to print and view a string, for debugging purposes, in a Java Google App Engine App?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, debugging

I'm building a web app using Java Google App Engine. I would like to do print statements and view them somewhere in order to debug my code. I was looking into logging, which is described here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/logs/. But, unfortunately, when I go to the Logs Viewer, I only see the status of my GET and POST requests but not the strings I logged. Anyone know why this is happening? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal? Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Below is how I'm trying to log.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName());
```

```
log.info("Successfully logged in!");
```

I also see this when I go to my Logs Viewer:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the logging method described in the docs that you mentioned, whatever you log should appear **inside** the log entry of your GET or POST requests, specifically in the  `protoPayload.line` property.

For your reference, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java8/requests/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/requests/LoggingServlet.java) you have a working example of the implementation of this logging technique.